# What is this black thing on my mouse's cable? Is it related to the mouse not working?

Tags: wire, ferrite, mouse

I was curious so I got an old mouse that doesn't work and decided to try and fix it. I got it open and tested the four wires coming from the cable with a multimeter but nothing anywhere. I thought either the USB thing is broken or something in the cable is broken.

I first suspected the weird black cylinder (google says it is a ferrite core,) so I opened it and found something hard - the ferrite core, I believe. Could this being broken or something be the reason it isn't working or should I check the other things?

Comment: Please provide details (preferably a photo) of the PCB and how you measured, how you concluded where GND is located and so on. The ferrite is very unlikely the culprit unless the wire is off or has a cold solder joint etc somewhere along the way.

Answer (score 5):

The ferrite core on a mouse cable is simply a tube-shaped piece of magnetic material that the cable passes through. It is there to reduce radio frequency signals on the cable. It will have nothing to do with continuity of the conductors, although because it is inflexible there can be more stress on the cable at that point so the cable may break there but that’s far less likely than it breaking at the USB connector or where it enters the mouse. Those are the most common places the cable will break.